# Extending endsession endpoint

Tags: .net, openid-connect, identityserver3

We need to create a custom logout event every time a user logs out or times out, but endsession controller is internal and not possible to inherit. Is there any way of injecting a piece of code to run on each logout given this obstacle?

Comment: Can you fire your event at the time the application is requested to log out? The application typically just redirects to the endsession endpoint anyway, you can do custom stuff before that. Alternatively the client is configured with a "postlogout redirect" uri, can you fire your event at that location? That way you're guaranteed the logout succeeded (unlike the first method)

Comment: @CrescentFresh thanks for the feedback. There might not be app request for logout, only timeout. Also, there are different types of clients using different flows, so it would be ideal to have one solution for all...

Comment: I see. I actually didn't realize this endpoint is used for "timeout", good tip! Re your second point, we routinely point multiple clients to the same postlogout uris, it allows us to centralize logic on what to do after a user logs out.

Comment: @CrescentFresh, another point on the logout uri, the information about the user that has been logged out wouldn't be available at this point. We need the info on the user about to be logged out for logging.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core?  If so, you might look at `services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(options => options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents{OnRemoteSignOut = (context) => ...`  I'm not positive how this handles the timeout you mentioned, but it should fire every time the user is logged out and you can inject it early.  [Link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-2.2).